# Apply a Function Pairwise

Tags: functions

I'm new to Mathematica

I'd like to apply `Mean` pairwise to a list to achieve the following.

```
badSource = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}};
badInterpolation = {{.5, .5}, {1.5, .5}, {2.5, .5}, {3.5, .5}};
ListLinePlot[{badSource, badInterpolation}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Pairwise Mean]

**How can this be done in general? Do I need pure functions?**

Comment: Mean /@ Partition[N@badSource, 2, 1]

Comment: MovingAverage[N@badSource, 2]

Comment: Nice. There seems so be a specific solution to everything in Mathematica :-)

Comment: @BoLe Although the answers are short it's preferable that you provide them as answers, not comments.  Otherwise, we'll have another seemingly unanswered question.

Comment: @BoLe, yup, those sure do look like answers to me. You might consider also including the `ListConvolve[]`/`ListCorrelate[]` version to cover all the bases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need partitioning, `Partition` and parameters: 2 for pairs, 1 for unit overhang/offset, and then averaging each pair, using `Map`, short-notated `/@`.

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 2, 1]

{{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}}
```

These will all make the averages:

```
Mean /@ Partition[N@badSource, 2, 1]

MovingAverage[N@badSource, 2]

ListConvolve[{{.5}, {.5}}, badSource]

ListCorrelate[{{.5}, {.5}}, badSource]
```

Last two suggested by J. M.

Comment: Instead of the form `f /@ Partition[list, ...]` use ``Developer`PartitionMap[f, list, ...]``.

Comment: @rcollyer why? Is it faster?

Comment: @chris I don't know. Intention wise, it is more apparent, and you can add ``Developer` `` to your `$ContextPath`, so it is almost as simple to type.

Comment: @rcollyer Great, I didn't know for these additional functions. Help says `PartitionMap[f, list, n]` is equivalent to `Map[f, Partition[list, n]]`. Does this, *being equivalent*, in general means that two calls always return same result yet they don't need to be implemented in the same way?

Comment: I _suspect_, that ``Developer`PartitionMap`` is implemented in terms of `Map` and `Partition`, so equivalence (i.e. they always return the same thing) would then be guaranteed. I have not seen the underlying code, so it is merely a suspicion, though a likely one.

Comment: @rcollyer I assume that `PartitionMap` is *not* implemented in terms of `Map` and `Partition`, at least not in their normal syntax and behavior.  The latter will do the full partitioning first, *then* the mapping.  `PartitionMap` does the mapping *while* the partitioning is done.  For example, `RandomChoice /@ Partition[Range@1*^6, 100, 1];` will use ~800MB of memory (peak), whereas `PartitionMap[RandomChoice, Range@1*^6, 100, 1];` will use ~23MB.

Comment: @chris the above is for you too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're right, I wasn't thinking when I wrote that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Experiment is the king. On a side note, I recieved a silver badge for this answer, the lamest sort of.