# Sectional averages of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am working in Mathematica.
I have a table of 200 elements. I want to calculate the mean value for the first 20 elements, for the second 20 elements  and so on, up to 200.
I will get a table (matrix) of 10 elements.
How I can solve this problem?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your question is specific enough to have a proper title ;) And try `Mean /@ Partition[data, 20]`

Comment: I'd like to reopen this as I think it has some value but I don't want to be heavy handed.  Does anyone agree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard one agrees. But why not simply put it to the reopen vote?

Comment: @Yves Thanks.  As a moderator I cannot cast a "normal" reopen vote; it will directly reopen the Question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - since your blockAverage2 is significantly faster than all other alternatives I tried it MUST be reopened!

Comment: @eldo That makes three votes, counting my own.  I'm going to reopen.

Answer (score 15):

As [Öskå](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1356/oska) notes you can [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) your data and then [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Mean.html):

```
a = {q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y};

Mean /@ Partition[a, 3]
```

> ```
> {1/3 (q + r + s), 1/3 (t + u + v), 1/3 (w + x + y)}
> ```

However if performance is a concern I propose using [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Total.html) or [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dot.html):

```
blockAverage1[a_List, n_Integer] := a ~Partition~ n ~Total~ {2} / n
blockAverage2[a_List, n_Integer] := Partition[a, n].ConstantArray[1/n, n]
```

Timings:

```
a = RandomReal[9, 5*^7]; (* big list *)

Mean /@ Partition[a, 20] // Timing // First
blockAverage1[a, 20]     // Timing // First
blockAverage2[a, 20]     // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.311
>
> 0.0654
>
> 0.0306
> ```

If you want averages of overlapping blocks see also:

- [Taking averages at certain intervals](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28240/121)
- [Finding the midpoints of an ordered list of numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29644/121)

Related:

- [Apply a Function Pairwise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25054/121)
- [How to find first list element that differs from average of N previous elements by more than a given amount?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31615/121)
- [How to partition three years of data into daily samples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45926/121)

Answer (score 8):

In versions 10.2+ there is `BlockMap`:

```
a = {q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y};

BlockMap[Mean, a, 3]
```

> {1/3 (q + r + s), 1/3 (t + u + v), 1/3 (w + x + y)}

Although this is much slower than the alternatives in Mr.Wizard's answer, its elegance may be of value since OP says

> *I have a table of 200 elements*

Also, an undocumented 6-argument form of `Partition`:

```
Partition[a, 3, 3, None, {}, Mean[{##}] &]
```

> {1/3 (q + r + s), 1/3 (t + u + v), 1/3 (w + x + y)}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y};
```

Using `SequenceCases` (new in 10.1)

```
SequenceCases[list, x : {_, _, _} :> Mean @ x]
```

{(q + r + s)/3, (t + u + v)/3, (w + x + y)/3}

Generalization

```
SequenceCases[list, x : {Repeated[_, {2}]} :> Mean @ x]
```

{(q + r)/2, (s + t)/2, (u + v)/2, (w + x)/2}

Answer (score 1):

Using `SubsetCases`:

```
list = {q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y};

SubsetCases[list, s : {_, _, _} :> Mean@s]

(*{1/3 (q + r + s), 1/3 (t + u + v), 1/3 (w + x + y)}*)
```

Or using `SequenceSplit`:

```
SequenceSplit[list, s : {_, _, _} :> Mean@s]

(*{1/3 (q + r + s), 1/3 (t + u + v), 1/3 (w + x + y)}*)
```